# python3 csv.writerows() puts cr after each row on Linux

Tags: python, csv

Many people have asked why csv.writerows() produces \r\n\n on windows, and have been advised to open the file with newline=''. But on Linux, my problem is the reverse, I get \r\n when I wanted \n and I can't get rid of the carriage return

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
  
import csv

with open("position.csv", 'w',newline='') as file:
  writer = csv.writer(file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
  lat=3.7
  long=4.5
  writer.writerow(['coords', lat,long])

od -cd position.csv 
0000000   "   c   o   o   r   d   s   "   ,   3   .   7   ,   4   .   5
          25378   28527   25714    8819   13100   14126   13356   13614
0000020  \r  \n
           2573
0000022
```

If I open with 'wb', then it complains I am writing strings, not binary

Comment: Try `writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator=os.linesep)` - it seems that `csv` package will write various dialects of CSV, with the default not being dependent on what OS it is running on. Hopefully the use of `os.linesep` will allow you to match it to the platform you are on - I don't have access to a Windows Python installation to check, but it certainly works on Linux.

Comment: That worked thanks. I wish the authors would have the default  honour OS conventions.

Comment: I can see arguments for and against. By the way, I would write this as an answer but I'm not completely comfortable to do so when I can't actually test it on Windows, so I'll leave it to someone who can properly test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  
import csv

with open("position.csv", 'w',newline='') as file:
  writer = csv.writer(file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,lineterminator='\n')
  lat=3.7
  long=4.5
  writer.writerow(['coords', lat,long])
```